# Index error from a point list that has enough entries

Tags: c#, .net, forms

So I wrote a bit of code that saves coordinates in order to recreate a custom drawn line and want to now redraw it using a method that uses graphics in order to do so: My method gets a list with 150 items of coordinates in the type of Point and an object that was saved when it was drawn.

```
public override void redraw(List<Point> list, object o,SchetchControl s)
{
     
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == list.Count)
        {
            s.MakeBitmapGraphics().DrawLine(MakePen(this.brush, 3), list[i], list[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            s.MakeBitmapGraphics().DrawLine(MakePen(this.brush, 3), list[i], list[i+1])
        }
      
    }
    s.Invalidate();
    s.Refresh();
   
}
```

The error seems to be in the indexing of the list and not in methods like makepen and graphics etc
The s.Makebitmap refers to the current bitmap graphics
The following error occurs:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'

Comment: Hint: the last iteration has `i == list.Count - 1`, not `i == list.Count`

Comment: Very dumb of me to not count that one its weird that the error occured on the second one tho even though my error was on the first if statement :/